# Should I close JNDI-obtained data source?

Tags: spring, tomcat7, datasource, jndi, spring-jdbc

Update: Apparently Tomcat, starting with 7.0.11, closes the DataSource for you, so it's not available in the webapp's contextDestroyed.  See: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25060

Hi,

I'm using Spring 3.0 and Java 1.6.

If I get a data source this way:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="my.data.Source" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:home"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pw"/>
</bean>
```

then the data source is closed when the bean is destroyed.

If I get the data source like this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/db" />
```

then do I have to explicitly close the data source in my contextDestroyed listener?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree.  I would add a listener to your web.xml and implement the contextDestroyed() method.  This method will get called by your web container/app server when the web app is destroyed or undeployed.  Within the contextDestroyed(), I would close the datasource.

inside the web.xml

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>util.myApplicationWatcher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The code:

```
package util;

public class myApplicationWatcher implementes ServletContextListener
{
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent cs)
  {
      // This web application is getting started

      // Initialize connection pool here by running a query
      JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(Dao.getDataSource() );
      jt.queryForInt("Select count(col1) from some_table");
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServeletContextEvent ce)
  {
      // This web application is getting undeployed or destroyed 

      // close the connection pool
      Dao.closeDataSource();
  }
}

public class Dao
{
  private static DataSource ds;
  private static bDataSourceInitialized=false;
  private static void initializeDataSource() throws Exception
  {
    InitialContext initial = new InitialContext();

    ds = (DataSource) initial.lookup(TOMCAT_JNDI_NAME);

    if (ds.getConnection() == null)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("I failed to find the TOMCAT_JNDI_NAME");
    }

    bDataSourceInitialized=true;
  }

  public static void closeDataSource() throws Exception
  {
    // Cast my DataSource class to a c3po connection pool class
    // since c3po is what I use in my context.xml
    ComboPooledDataSource cs = (ComboPooledDatasource) ds;

    // close this connection pool
    cs.close();
  }

  public static DataSource getDataSource() throws Exception
  {
    if (bDataSourceInitialized==false)
    {
      initializeDataSource();
    }

    return(ds);
  }
}
```

Comment: It turns out this is the correct answer.  I posted the question to the Tomcat mailing list and one of the [responses](https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#label/tomcat+mailing+list/12eee26933b45474) said that because the EE spec said JNDI resources are created when they are looked up (because, I assume, is that java:comp resources are not shared between components) the webapp should deal with it in contextDestroyed.

Comment: Looks like Tomcat 7 will take care of the datasource for you: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25060

Answer (score 4):

No.  The `DataSource` here is managed by the remote JNDI container, and it's that container's job to manage the lifecycle of the `DataSource`.  Spring just makes use of it, it doesn't manage it.

Even if you wanted to, you couldn't - `DataSource` has no `close()` method, or anything like it.

Comment: I was casting the DataSource to the underlying class (e.g. BasicDataSource) and calling that class' close method.  Is that a bad thing or just unnecessary?  Is there anything I should do to clean up data access in contextDestroyed?

Answer (score 1):

When you get the data source through a JNDI lookup it a shared resource - configured in your container.  It is managed by the container and not by the application, so it is not required (there is no way) to close it.