# Lot's of connections as sleep causing too many connections error

Tags: mysql, tomcat, hikaricp

I implemented Hikari Connection Pooling.

This is my config for the pooling thing.

```
        config.setUsername("abc");
        config.setPassword("abc");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("maximumPoolSize", "10");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("maxLifetime", "60");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Problem is that, there are lot's and lot's of(Around 150) connections under `command` as sleep when I execute `show processlist`.

This causes "too many connections" issue.

[image] I have two web apps which connect to this db but even if I undeploy them, meaning there are no web apps trying to connect with the db, I still see that the number of connections which are allowed are exhausted.

I have thoroughly gone through similar questions on SO, none is helping me out.

Comment: Strictly from a high-level, generic troubleshooting perspective, your application can `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()` and log the value -- which corresponds to the `Id` shown in the processlist, to help you understand how the pooling is (or isn't working).  I suspect your code leaks connections, which would explain this.  Maybe something like `config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(20000);` would call these out.

Comment: Additionally, `maximumPoolSize` should be set via `config.setMaximumPoolSize(10)`.  And `maxLifetime` should be set via `config.setMaxLifetime(60 * 60 * 1000)` (for one hour).  All HikariCP times and timeouts are in _milliseconds_.  As a side node, a `maxLifetime` of 60 *seconds* would be counter-productive; I don't recommand any value less than 5 minutes.  If you want faster retirement, and a minimal sized pool, use `minimumIdle` and `idleTimeout`.

Comment: Enable DEBUG level logging for `com.zaxxer.hikari`.  It almost sounds like you are creating _many pools_ -- each of which will create 10 connections.  Debug logging will reveal whether that is the case.

Comment: i am pretty sure that i was using the connection as singleton i.e one for the whole project. What I figured out is that, when I undeployed the app from tomcat, the connections were not closing down( dunno why?), so what I did is that I added a `HikariDataSource.close` under destroy method of servlet. Is this a good approach?

Comment: @driftking9987 The servlet is the wrong place to manage the lifecycle.  You should implement a `ServletContextListener`, similar to that described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407525/should-i-close-jndi-obtained-data-source.  If you are not using JNDI, the the `contextInitialized()` method would be a good place to initialize the database, with the destroy obviously in the `contextDestroyed()` method.